# Performance tuning Entity Framework queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

So I've developed a dashboard which queries a database.  The database has data stored in it from google analytics for a website we have.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, EF, Linq with Telerik controls/widgets.  The controller instantiates a service layer where I have my db context and business logic.  Each svc.method() pertains to a specific result set I'm after that I package up in the VM for unpackaging into a widget within the view.

Currently, the response time in the network tab of Google Chrome is 5.6 seconds.  I've illustrated one of the 8 methods to show you my approach.

My question is; how can I improve performance so that the page loads faster?  Would making each method async improve it?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult WebStats()
    {
        //other code removed for brevity

        //Service layer where the db is queried and the business logic is performend
        WebStatsService svc = new WebStatsService();

        //view model 
    WebStatsViewModel vm = new WebStatsViewModel();

        vm.PageViews = svc.GetPageViews(vm);
        vm.UniquePageViews = svc.GetUniquePageViews(vm);
        vm.UserRatioByCountry = svc.GetUserRatioByCountry(vm);
        vm.PageViewsByCountry = svc.GetPageViewsByCountry(vm);
        vm.TopTenHealthCenters = svc.GetTopTenHealthCenters(vm);
        vm.UserTypeRatio = svc.GetUserTypeRatio(vm);
        vm.TopTenHealthCentersByDateRange = svc.GetTopTenHealthCentersByDateRange(vm);
        vm.ReferralSources = svc.GetTopTenReferralSources(vm);//Get top 10 referral paths


        return View(vm);
    }
```

Service:

```
    public List<PageViews> GetPageViews(WebStatsViewModel vm)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            List<PageViews> pageViewStats = new List<PageViews>();

            var results = db.PageStats.Where(x => (vm.CMS.Equals("All") || x.Source.Equals(vm.CMS))
                                               && (vm.HealthCenter.Equals("All") || x.HealthSectionName.Equals(vm.HealthCenter))
                                               && (vm.Country.Equals("All") || x.Country.Equals(vm.Country))
                                               && (vm.City.Equals("All") || x.City.Equals(vm.City))
                                               && (x.Date >= vm.StartDate)
                                               && (x.Date <= vm.EndDate)
                                            ).Select(x => new
                                            {
                                                Date = x.Date,
                                                Total = x.PageViews
                                            }).ToList();

            var distinctDate = results.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Date).Distinct();

            foreach (var date in distinctDate)
            {
                PageViews pageViewStat = new PageViews();

                pageViewStat.Date = date.Value.ToShortDateString();
                pageViewStat.Total = results.Where(x => x.Date == date).Sum(x => x.Total);

                pageViewStats.Add(pageViewStat);
            }

            return pageViewStats;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is really too broad a question for this site. You may get some benefit from making it async, but your mileage may vary on that. We *may* be able to help you performance tune *one* of your queries here, but not the general layout/performance.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG.  I'm looking at improving the query response time, the view performance is a different story.  That said, I'm looking for advise on different approaches e.g. would making each widget a partial view improve response performance?  I'm looking for suggestions on different strategies.

Comment: Advice would just be opinion, another reason why this isn't a good fit for SO. Having sad that, I'd be tempted to load the data on your view via AJAX calls, that way the page will display as each part is retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some tips for EF queries:

(1) Avoid mixing constant and actual predicate in dynamic filters like this:

```
(vm.CMS.Equals("All") || x.Source.Equals(vm.CMS))
```

It might look concise, but generates awful and inefficient SQL. Instead, use `if` statements and chained `Where`:

```
// Base query including static filters
var query = db.PageStats.AsQueryable();
// Apply dynamic filters
if (!vm.CMS.Equals("All"))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Source.Equals(vm.CMS));
// ...
// The rest of the query
query = query.Select(...
```

(2) Try returning as less data as possible from the SQL query.

For instance, your query is populating a list with `(Date, Total)` pairs, which you then manually (and not very efficiently) group by `Date` and take `Sum(Total)`. Instead, you can make the EF query directly return that grouped/aggregated data.

Applying all that to your example would lead to something like this:

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var query = db.PageStats
        .Where(x => x.Date >= vm.StartDate && x.Date <= vm.EndDate);

    if (!vm.CMS.Equals("All"))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Source.Equals(vm.CMS));
    if (!vm.HealthCenter.Equals("All"))
        query = query.Where(x => x.HealthSectionName.Equals(vm.HealthCenter));
    if (!vm.Country.Equals("All"))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Country.Equals(vm.Country));
    if (!vm.City.Equals("All"))
        query = query.Where(x => x.City.Equals(vm.City));

    query = query
        .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
        .Select(g => new
        {
            Date = g.Key,
            Total = g.Sum(x => x.PageViews)
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Date);

    var pageViewStats = query
        .AsEnumerable() // SQL query ends here
        .Select(x => new PageViews
        {
            Date = x.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(),     
            Total = x.Total
        })
        .ToList();

    return pageViewStats;
}
```

You can try and compare the performance with the original.

(Note: for this specific query we need to use two projections - one temporary in SQL query and one final in the in memory query. This is because of the need of `ToShortDateString()` method which is not supported for the SQL query. In most of the cases a single final projection in the SQL query would be sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks, Ivan.  Goes to show how I still need to improve my linq abilities... So does the query not execute until .AsEnumerable()?  Curious how your suggestion for the SQL execution is deferred and when it executes.

Comment: Actually it's get executed by the `ToList` call. `AsEnumerable` just switches the context from `IQueryable` (hence under control of the query provider) to `IEnumerable` (i.e. LINQ to Objects - based on extension methods contained in the `Enumerable` class). As long as you keep chaining methods on `IQueryable`, they are translated to SQL. `IEnumerable` methods are executed in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

1. Indexes - index columns that appear in the where clause of select operations, use SQL profiler to detect 'table scan' operations and add indexes to avoid them (replace them with index search or clustered index search)
2. Caching - store the trace from SQL profiler above to a table in DB (SQL Profiler can do it) and group SQL commands by sql text, this may show some repeating selects that can be avoided by caching
3. Glimpse - can count SQL commands per web request, the number can be suprising if the web application has not been optimized yet. Glimpse can tell much more, for example how much time of the total time of a web request is spent on the server and how much time in the web browser rendering the page.
4. as the last resort, write your own SQL for the most exposed queries